# What is the best method to edtit a .txt file on a FTP server in the same time for 100 persons for example?

Tags: powershell

What is the best method to edit a .txt file on a FTP server?

I have a remote ftp file1.txt .100 persons or 100 servers mut add a value $y=" yes" to file1.txt in the same time...So it is not possible to use the  method in my case:

```
 Download file
 Edit file locally (in memory)
 Upload file
```

I Want to do this and I can use only a method with FTP for security reasons:

```
$pathftp="ftp:\\......file1.txt"
$y=yes

add-content - path $pathftp -$y
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$a="test5"
$FTPServer = 'ftp://localhost'
$FTPUsername = 'username'
$FTPPassword = 'password'
$FTPSecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $FTPPassword -asPlainText -Force
$FTPCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($FTPUsername,$FTPSecurePassword)
Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $FTPCredential -Server $FTPServer -Session MySession -UsePassive 
$Session = Get-FTPConnection -Session MySession 
$b=Get-FTPChildItem -Session $Session -Path / -Recurse | Where-Object{$_.Name -like "file1.txt"} 
Add-Content -Path $b -Value -$a
```

Comment: Is it absolutely required for all clients to share and write to a single file on the server?  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: yes. I have a script powershell which make all the updates of a program automatically .This program is installed on 100 servers.when an update is failed, a server must write on a  file1.txt which is  on a FTP server

Comment: Text files are not designed for shared use. If you need this functionality, move to using a database that is designed for that purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to add a value to a remote ftp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66282286/i-want-to-add-a-value-to-a-remote-ftp-file)

Comment: @PowerCat The issue is that there are many clients that will be performing this operation, creating the potential for a race condition as to which client's update actually gets persisted.  There needs to be synchronized access to the remote file, which I don't believe FTP provides a mechanism for.